# HKDF or PBKDF2 for generating key for symmetric encryption? (Python Cryptography)

Tags: python, encryption

I have an application where I encrypt some text for a user.

As of now, the user enters a plain-text password, and then I run an [HKDF algorithm via the Cryptography package](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/key-derivation-functions/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.hkdf.HKDF) to derive a key from that password. After converting the key to a URL-safe base64-encoded 32-byte key, I use it as the key for running symmetric encryption (using the [Fernet module](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/#cryptography.fernet.Fernet)) to encrypt the user's text.

I've read up on HKDF, and read that the "extract-then-expand" paradigm makes it useful for this type of scenario. But I've also read the documentation which states HKDF is not good for password storage. So I'm wondering if I should be using a [PBKDF2 algorithm](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/key-derivation-functions/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2.PBKDF2HMAC) in this scenario instead?

I'm not storing the plain-text password, or the keys I derive from them though, which is why I thought HKDF would be ok. I want to make sure I'm doing things securely, and could use any help from someone more experienced.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I just came across this helpful post https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38303/hkdf-and-key-stretching, which leads me to believe I should be using PBKDF2. Still would like some confirmation though if possible.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be using PBKDF2 instead of HKDF for one big reason: key-stretching, which "stretches" the amount of time it takes to generate the key from a password and which HKDF does not provide. HKDF is fast, PBKDF2 is slow. The slower, the better, for when an attacker tries a million different passwords -- you want the attacker to give up because it takes too long. Read this answer here for more details: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38303/hkdf-and-key-stretching.

Comment: I think an HMAC might provide better properties under some conditions. For example, if I use `streched = Hash(SHA1, "password")`, then the attacker can get an answer rather quickly by turning to Google. Just search for "c8fed00eb2e87f1cee8e90ebbe870c190ac3848c". If I use `streched = HMAC(SHA1, key, "password")`, then Google can't return an answer unless it knows the key. I'm pretty sure its because an HMAC is a  PRF, and a Hash is not.

Comment: @jww PBKDF2 and HKDF both usually rely on HMAC.